# Extending DateTime class

Tags: php, datetime, extends

I am trying to extend the DateTime class:

```
class Test extends DateTime {
    public function format($format) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This works fine, but if I try to declare the type of the argument as follows:

```
class Test extends DateTime {
    public function format(string $format) : string {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> PHP Fatal error: Declaration of Test::format(string $format): string must be compatible with DateTime::format($format)

According to the [DateTime declaration](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), **string** is the expected type.

Comment: Since `DateTime::format` is an internal implementation, it may not use explicit type annotations, so adding any makes it incompatible.

Comment: @deceze I've been checking the definition in the PHP source code and the type is declared: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/date/php_date.stub.php#L170

Comment: That’s the userland stub, from where you might get IDE auto completion and/or the documentation; it’s not the actual implementation.

Comment: When standard PHP classes are expanded, it is not a good idea to give existing methods a other functionality.
Choose another name like formatX and you won't have any problems.